# Find $f(\mathbb D)$

Tags: calculus, functions, quadratics

If $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x}-x}{\sqrt{x}+2}$ and $x\in\mathbb D=[0,\infty]$ find $$f(\mathbb D)$$.
I've tried to solve equation $y=f(x)$ and stopped to $x+(y-1)\sqrt{x}+2y=0$.

Comment: What is $f(0)$? What happens when $x$ is large?  Are there values for which $f'(x)=0$?  Since $x$ is non-negative, might it be easier to let $z=\sqrt{x}$ and consider $g(z)=\dfrac{z-z^2}{z+2}$?

Comment: Umm. A partial fraction looks good

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x}-x}{\sqrt{x}+2}=\frac{\sqrt{x}+2-2-x}{\sqrt{x}+2}=1-\frac{{x}+2}{\sqrt(x)+2}$
$f(x)\leq1$
gives the upper bound

Now can you handle it

Comment: You might want to check the signs